# Extract Plugin Name from file with grep

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

In a shell script I get the version of a WordPress plugin file with this line:

```
VERSION=`grep "^Version" $PLUGIN | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r'`
```

`$VERSION` contains the version number from the file (e.g. *2.1*)

The problem seems to be with the space character when I try to get the name:

```
PLUGINNAME=`grep "^Plugin Name" $PLUGIN | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r'`
```

`$PLUGINNAME` contains `Name:` but not the plugin.

`$PLUGIN` is the location of the plugin file e.g. `my-plugin/index.php`

Here's the content of this file (stripped):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin Name
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: the description of the plugin
Version: 2.1
Author: revaxarts.com
Author URI: http://example.com
*/

// -- stripped -- //
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a look-behind with `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=^Version: ).*' your_file.php
2.1
$ grep -Po '(?<=^Plugin Name: ).*' your_file.php
My Plugin Name
```

This looks for all the text after `Version:` or `Plugin Name:` when such strings occur at the beginning of a line.

---

Since this uses the `-P` for Perl regular expressions, which is not available in your OS X, let's go for `awk`:

```
awk -F": " '/^Plugin Name:/ {print $2}' file
```

This gets lines starting with `Plugin Name:` and prints the second field, considering fields as `:`- separated (`:` plus space).

---

To store the values in a variable, just use the `var=$(command)` syntax:

```
plugin_name=$(awk -F": " '/^Plugin Name:/ {print $2}' file)
```

Comment: I need it in a variable. Can you update the answer pls?

Comment: I always get the "how to use" message :( (There's no `-P` option)

Comment: I'm on a mac. `usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]``  http://ss64.com/osx/grep.html

Comment: @revaxarts this is because `-P` is not allowed in that grep version. Try to use `awk -F": " '/^Plugin Name:/ {print $2}' file` instead.

Comment: bam!, works. Can you update the answer so I can accept it? Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your time!